# sklearn: MultiClass Classifier with Negative Samples

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I am new to Machine Learning, however, a veteran programmer....

I have a lot of data about Customer/Agent interactions, with ratings for these interactions as being positive/negative from the customer perspective... I also have lots of features about the customer (Age, Gender, previous spend, products purchased,....etc)

I want to train a model that can learn from Customer Features who is the best Agent to deal with them that would potentially produce the highest rating... Assuming that similar customers (similar features) would lead to the Agent being able to serve them in the same way.....

Assume the following pandas Dataframe: dataset

```
    AgentID Score Cust_F1 Cust_F2 Cust_F3 ..... Cust_Fn
0   1        10      1      0       1             2
1   1         0      0      1       2             0
2   1         9      1      2       1             2
3   2        10      0      1       1             1 
4   2         9      0      1       2             1
5   2         0      1      0       2             2


X = dataset.drop([['AgendID','Score']],1).values
y = dataset['AgentID'].values

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=1)
clf.fit(X,y)
```

I want a way to train the model to reject (negative train) all samples with Score = 0. I cannot find a way to do this with sklearn... Of course, I can remove samples with Scores = 0 from the training data, however, I believe they are very valuable information that would help the algorithm to properly classify...

I also looked at sample_weight parameter and i thought if I put negative values there it would help, however, the documentation doesn't mention this...

Can someone please help me...

Comment: Answer the following questions first. 1. Is it a regression or classification proble? 2. If classification, how many classes are there. You could probably encode `score=0` into one of the classes.

Comment: It is a classification problem... I need to know which is the best agent to handle the customer. There are thousands of Agents,  i.e thousands of classes... I don't understand your comment about `score=0`, I will check the documentation to understand more.